# vim auto inserting inserted text

Tags: vim

Whenever I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> it inserts previously inserted characters when in Edit mode. What feature is this? How can I disable it?

Also when editing if I haven't typed anything and I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I see the following warning:  `"E29: No inserted text yet"`.

Comment: do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: Can you post your .vimrc here?

Comment: Seems like the functionality of `CTRL-@`. When I once experienced this kind of issue, it was caused by one key on my keyboard sending `NUL` on press (because my keyboard had more keys than my keymap (en-US) uses).

Comment: This happened even when I loaded vim with no vimrc file (-u /dev/null) Strange part is I can't always reproduce this. But when it happens it's bloody annoying.

Comment: @Yosh That sounds like a plausible explanation. I use iTerm2 to ssh to a remote host and observed the issue there. Not in my local host though.

Comment: @Jithin If this is really the case, you can try `inoremap <C-@> <Esc>`. Nothing more than a workaround (thus not an answer to the question), but it will probably work.

Comment: On OSX. This is an issue for me as well, but i tracked this issue back to iTerm2. I have no problem in native OSX terminal

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Getting out of insert mode with ESC followed by 'k' inserts lines above again. Only happens when I'm using 'TotalTerminal' on OSX...